# Populate many Html elements inside a div with golang templates?

Tags: go, go-templates

I receive from my frontend a json with a string containing 1 or more HTML elements for example:

`"textTop" : "<b>bold</b><div><i>italic</i>..."`

I want to use this string to create Html elements inside a div, but I'm not really sure if I can do this with golang templates.

```
type FooBar struct {
    TextTop    string
}
```

So I'm currently storing the TextTop in a string, and then displaying it in html with:

```
        <div>
            {{.TextTop}}
        </div>
```

But of course this produces the following result in the browser. just a div containing the **string**, I'm passing.: 
[image]

So should I use a different type for `TextTop` inside `Foobar struct` instead of type string, which one? or can I use a golang function that reads all html elements from a string and renders them in the html as part of the DOM and not just a string?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Inserting HTML to golang template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41931082/inserting-html-to-golang-template)

Answer (score 3):

To prevent escaping, declare the field as type [template.HTML](https://godoc.org/html/template#HTML):

```
type FooBar struct {
    TextTop    template.HTML
}
```

See the linked documentation for information about the security risks of using template.HTML.